# Component with local state not updating on React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to create a standalone component `MultiSelect` (I know there are components out there but I want to learn how to do one).

I created it in a way it will store the selected values in its state.

I call it like this from my container:

```
<MultiSelect
  items={ this.props.boards }
  label="Boards"
  value={ this.props.selectedBoards }
  onChange={ e => this.onChange(e) } />
```

When I dispatch an action I get the correct values for the container's props. My MultiSelect even display the correct options. However for some reason it doesn't update the selected values. In the container `this.props.selectedBoards` has the correct value, but the component doesn't get this update.

```
export default class MultiSelect extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); // props.items = all options to select

    this.state = {
      selectedItems: props.value || [], // selected options (problem)
      search: '',
      hidden: true,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>
      ...
      this.state.selectedItems
```

The options to select is on the `props` (which works) and the selected options is on the `state` (which doesn't get updated).

How can I make the `MultiSelect` component update with a new value for `selectedItems` which is in the state? Or what would be the recommended way to create a component like this?

Answer (score 0):

I end up moving `selectedItems` from the `state` to the `props`, and then on the `onChange` event where elements get selected I'm getting the value from the `props`, adding/removing the changed item and calling `this.props.onChange` with the modified array.

Then on the container I'm dispatching an action with the new array so I can get a new state.

I solved it by delegating the task to keep track of selected items to the container.

MultiSelect:

```
export default class MultiSelect extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      search: '',
      hidden: true,
    };
  }

  onChange(item) {
    const selectedItems = [ ...this.props.selectedItems ];

    const index = selectedItems.findIndex(element => element.value === item.value);

    if (index !== -1) {
      selectedItems.splice(index, 1);
    }
    else {
      selectedItems.push(item);
    }

    this.props.onChange(selectedItems); // container
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>
      ...
      this.props.selectedItems
```

Container:

```
onChange(data) {
  this.props.dispatch({ type: 'SetSelectedBoards', data });
}

<MultiSelect
  items={ this.props.boards }
  label="Boards"
  selectedItems={ this.props.selectedBoards }
  onChange={ e => this.onChange(e) } />
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but if you want to react to prop changes in the future, look into the `componentWillReceiveProps` method.